# Using SMO to backup SQL Server 2005 Database with C# Windows Forms Application, Back up failed

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, database-backups

This is my code to back up my database I followed [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SQL_Server_2005_Database.aspx), as you can see, the codes are identical. The error comes after I fill in the variables. The error I get is

> Backup failed for Server 'RITZEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS'.

**Back up function:**

```
    public void BackupDatabase(String databaseName, String userName, String password,        String serverName, String destinationPath)
    {
        Backup sqlBackup = new Backup();

        sqlBackup.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
        sqlBackup.BackupSetDescription = "ArchiveDataBase:" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        sqlBackup.BackupSetName = "Archive";

        sqlBackup.Database = databaseName;

        BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(destinationPath, DeviceType.File);
        ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(serverName, userName, password);
        Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);

        Database db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];

        sqlBackup.Initialize = true;
        sqlBackup.Checksum = true;
        sqlBackup.ContinueAfterError = true;

        sqlBackup.Devices.Add(deviceItem);
        sqlBackup.Incremental = false;

        sqlBackup.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);
        sqlBackup.LogTruncation = BackupTruncateLogType.Truncate;

        sqlBackup.FormatMedia = false;

        sqlBackup.SqlBackup(sqlServer);
    }
```

**Button click**

```
    private void BackUp_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String databaseName = @"D:\MY_THESIS\WORKING FILES\NNIT-RMS.mdf";
        String userName = "NNIT-Admin";
        String password = "password";
        String serverName = @"RITZEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS";
        String destinationPath = @"D:\";

        BackupDatabase(databaseName,userName,password,serverName,destinationPath);

    }
```

**Database Information**
I am not allowed to post images yet but I have uploaded a screen shot. See here: http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/9250/sqlg.jpg

Comment: The `databaseName` should be the **logical database name** of the database when it's attached to the SQL Server Express - e.g. `MYDATABASE` - and **not** the entire file name of the `.mdf` file. I don't think SMO allows you to back up a separate `.mdf` file

Comment: If you would look at the screen shot I posted above, I placed a screen shot of the database information of the database I want to backup. That is the name that appears on the database node in sqlserver2005. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I'm saying: you cannot backup a "stand-alone" `.mdf` file with SMO. You need to **attach** the `.mdf` file to your SQL Server Express, give it a **logical** database name, and then use that logical database name for your SMO backup. This whole "attach .mdf on the fly" feature is a bit of a mess and quite frankly should not be used - and will be discontinued in SQL Server 2012 ("Denali")

Answer (score 1):

In order to backup a database, the process SQL Server is running as need to have the correct folder permissions on the folder the backup is targeted at.

From my experience the unless the SQL server process is running as the local admin it wont have permission to write to the root directory.

If you open SSMS and try to backup the database to your destination path you might encounter the same issue.

Try changing the backup folder to something other than the root of the drive or your my documents folder.

Answer (score 0):

Don' assign again the string value u just remove them and call the backup like this:

```
BackupSqlDatabase("YourDataBaseName","sa","password","ServerName","C:\\YourDataBaseName.bak");
```